# Store duplicate data in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-6

Is there a way to map a certain field to multiple columns in Entity Framework? The specific scenario is using inheritance with Table per Type hierarchy . I would a certain field to appear in both the base type table and the concrete type table.

Example:

```
abstract class BaseEntity
{
     int id { get; set; }
     DateTime createDate { get; private set; }
     string TypeName { get; private set; }

}

public class Person : BaseEntity
{
     int id { get; set; }
     DateTime createDate { get; private set; }
     string TypeName { get; private set; }
     string FirstName {get; set;}
     string LastName {get; set;}
     DateTime DateOfBirth {get; set;}
}
```

Base Class Table

```
int ID,
DateTime createDate,
varchar TypeName
```

Concrete Class Table

```
int ID,
DateTime createDate,
varchar FirstName,
varchar LastName,
DateTime DateOfBirth
```

It is not an issue having ID in both tables because it is the primary key. However the create date is treated as separate data.

The main reason for this is for database maintenance and supportability. I understand that duplication of data is not a good practice. This would only be for a few fields.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible, this is also not good C# code as you will more than likely have a warning saying that CreateDate is shadowing an inherited property.

You can solve this by using a database trigger that inserts/updates the value after the insert/update in the derived table completes.

Comment: The c# code doesn't have to look like that. The property does not need to be readded to the Person Class if there is another way. I'd like the "trigger" your suggesting to do be done somehow in the code